# How do I get these big icons visible in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, icons, controls

I'm new to Xcode and I have a question that is more like simple to answer,

yes to these 
http://s7.postimg.org/vsnvft1e3/Screen_Shot_2015_08_27_at_09_47_38.png
no to this
http://s22.postimg.org/ma242zxox/Screen_Shot_2015_08_27_at_09_47_23.png

How do I get these big icons visible?

Answer (score 0):

Press that button where the arrow is pointing to:

[image]